# Next.js Google fonts don't load on the initial render

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, sass, next.js

I'm importing the Google fonts into the custom _document.tsx Head component, but the fonts don't load on the initial render. The fonts are only loaded when I visit another page. Fonts work fine in the dev environment (next dev), Its only happening in production (next build > next start).

I tried setting `display=optional` in the link, not using scss variables, but none of that worked.

I'm importing two google fonts in custom `_document.tsx` in `Head` like this:

```
<Head>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@300;400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Berkshire+Swash&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
</Head>
```

Setting it in `styles/variables.scss`:

```scss
$font: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
$font-hand: 'Berkshire Swash', cursive;
```

And using it like this in `styles/global.scss`:

```scss
@import './variables.scss';

body {
  font-family: $font;
}
```

And like this in `components/UI/header/header.module.scss`:

```scss
@import '../../../styles/variables.scss';

.logo {
  font-family: $font-hand;
}
```

Comment: I'm having the same problem, but have not found any answers. tried otf and woff, neither work.